# Save Image source to database

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `WPF Image` with a source assign from picture dialog;

```
this.imgProduct.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(op.FileName));
```

How can I retieve the source, convert it to `byte array` and save it into `database`?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert BitmapImage into the byte[] then save it to the database.

```
var imageSource = this.imgProduct.Source as BitmapImage;
var stream = imageSource.StreamSource;
Byte[] buffer = null;

if (stream != null && stream.Length > 0)
{
    using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(stream))
    {
        buffer = br.ReadBytes((Int32)stream.Length);
    }
}

// write buffer to the database
```

P.S. I haven't tested the code but I think it works!

Comment: StreamSource will be `null`, since the image was loaded from a Uri.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have access to the image file in `op.FileName` it would be very easy to get the file content by e.g.

```
byte[] imageBuffer = File.ReadAllBytes(op.FileName);
```

If the image is loaded from a file Uri (as in your example) you could also do this:

```
byte[] imageBuffer = File.ReadAllBytes(image.UriSource.AbsolutePath);
```

If you only have the BitmapImage without information about the file that it was loaded from (e.g. when it was loaded from a temporary file or a web resource), you would have to encode it by one of WPFs [BitmapEncoders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapencoder.aspx):

```
byte[] imageBuffer;
PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(image));

using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    encoder.Save(stream);
    imageBuffer = stream.GetBuffer();
}
```